# Query time out issue in snowflake

Tags: c#, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am getting a query time out problem when the query fails to execute within 45 seconds. I need some advice on how to set query time out for snowflake. FYI, I have tried using `query_Timeout` parameter in connection string which was mentioned in snowflake documentation.

Thinking this is about ODBC `commandTimeout`, I wanted to test if it fails by setting `commandTimeout=1(Second)`, surprisingly it does not fail.
I have also tried `connectionTimeout=1(Second)`

I get the following error

> ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (15)        Query has timed out.
>   User specified timeout in seconds=30, Elapsed=45

Comment: Can you run the query in the web interface of Snowflake? And what does SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE '%STATEMENT_TIMEOUT%'; give you?

This appears to be a problem on Snowflake's side, someone else had exactly the same issue before: https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00007yvyDZSAY/system-timeout

Comment: Have you tried this link?  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ecosystem-diagnose-connectivity-issues.html.  This is a good diagnostics tool if you are able to run your query from the Snowflake UI, but not through ODBC.  The default timeout on Snowflake is 2 days, so I doubt that Snowflake is the cause of your issue.  There could be a proxy or firewall that is timing you out somewhere along the way.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a user defined timeout setting. 
If you have access to the ACCOUNTADMIN Role, I would check the parameters as mentioned in the first comment of your question. The SQL would be like:

USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN; 
SHOW PARAMETERS IN USER  LIKE '%STATEMENT_TIMEOUT%';

Let them know if it helps!